# How do I install a Joomla template without having to delete my data

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying out a new template on a Joomla website I'm working. For the template to work, I need to isntall sample data. The template documentation requires install sample data, which will delete data.

Does installing Joomla template require installing sample data, thereby deleting current data in the process?

Is there any way for me to install templates without having to delete current data.

Comment: You could unzip the install file and see if you can delete the code related to the importing of sample data.

Comment: When you ask give complete details so that we dont have to scratch our head thinking about which template you might be using. If you hide details no one will be able to help you. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you install sample data, your data will be overwritten. You can make a backup before to installing the sample data. You have to backup both database and files. You can also use [Akeeba Backup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup/). However, I suggest you to make many backup in various forms.